# NodeJS multer filename for fields

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm nodeJS beginner. How to get filenames for multer storage fields?

controller:

```
exports.createTruckDocs = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("tu");
  Truck.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.truckId}, {$set: {TLic: /*issue*/}}).then(createdDocs => {
    res.status(201).json(createdDocs);
  })
};
```

middleware:

```
module.exports = multer({ storage: storage }).fields([
  { name: "TLIC"},
  { name: "LIC" },
  { name: "CMRLIC" }
]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Get the fileName from the request and save it? or You facing any errors?

Comment: Tnx @ApoorvaChikara. I want to store the filename. I found the correct syntax in multer documantation so if someone needs to get filename from multer fields it's: req.files['field name'][0].filename

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how you should save the file with multer. I am not sure which steps is confusing, but this is how you should do:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({   
   destination: function(req, file, cb) { 
      cb(null, './uploads');    // you can name the destination make sure it exists
   }, 
   filename: function (req, file, cb) { 
      cb(null , file.originalname);   
   }
});

// to save single files
//const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('fieldName')

// to save multiple files, you can also set limit
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('fieldName')
app.post("/upload_files", upload.array("fieldName"), uploadFiles);

const uploadFiles = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
    res.json({ message: "Successfully uploaded files" });
}
```

You can check [here](https://afteracademy.com/blog/file-upload-with-multer-in-nodejs-and-express#:%7E:text=Multer%20is%20a%20node.,handle%20multipart%2Fform%2Ddata.) for more details.

Comment: req.files['field name'][0].filename - that's what I needed

Comment: Good to see that you found what you need! If this answers help you in any way you can accept it and upvote it. thanx!